# Overflowing line of divs in div with scroll not new line

Tags: css, css-float

I have a div whith contains another divs with image. I need to have these divs in a on line but when I add another div whith don`t have enough place so this div go to a new line. Number of divs depend on number of images in db so I need scroll them.

css:

```
div#saved_images {
    width: 85%;
    height: 135px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border: 2px dashed #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div.saved_image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
    height: 120px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks for your input.
Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/Sc2L8/

Comment: I've done a jsfiddle of your thing. Seems to work for me in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should use "white-space:nowrap" in div#container.

```
div#container {
    width: 85%;
    height: 135px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border: 2px dashed #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this remove the whitespace? Like what if we wanted to make a new line on purpose? Nowrap removes that, right?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like typical case for floating. More about floats [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/):

so for ex.

```
div.saved_image { float:left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this style for the container

```
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: normal;
}
```